# Trying to run an Intraday Chart from Yahoo that runs and updates every 5 minutes Mondays through Fridays

Tags: python, graph, automation, finance, yahoo-finance

I have an LQD Price Graph importing data from Yahoo Finance. I think I have a pretty good base line of code but struggling to execute. Trying to run Funcanimation function to time the run in 5-minute intervals but getting some Attribute Errors. Essentially, I want the graph to run and update automatically. Thank you!

> ```
> def is_market_hours():
>      now=datetime.now()
>      market_start = now.replace(hour=9, minute=30, second= 0, microsecond=0)
>      market_end = now.replace(hour=16, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>      return market_start <= now <= market_end and now.weekday() , 5
>      def run_LQDYahoo():
>          if is_market_hours():
>              data = yf.download(tickers='LQD', period= '1d', interval = '5m')
>              fig = go.Figure()
>              fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=data.index, 
>                                          open=data['Open'],
>                                          high=data['High'],
>                                          low=data['Low'],
>                                          close=data['Close'], name = 'market data'))
>              fig.update_layout(
>                     title='LQD Live Price Evolution',
>                     yaxis_title='Price')
>              fig.update_xaxes(
>                     rangeslider_visible=True,
>                     rangeselector=dict(
>                          buttons=list([
>                             dict(count=15, label="15m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
>                             dict(count=45, label="45m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
>                             dict(count=1, label="HTD", step="hour", stepmode="todate"),
>                             dict(count=2, label="3h", step="hour", stepmode="backward"),
>                             dict(step="all")
>                          ])
>                     )
>                 )
>
> ani = FuncAnimation(fig, is_market_hours, frames = None, interval =300000)
>
> fig.show()
> ```